# Rspec - Syntax errors while testing users controler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I'm having an issue while testing user authentication with rspec and devise.

here is my code:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe UsersController, :type => :controller do

  let(:user) { User.create!(email: '1@test.com', password: '123456') }

  describe 'GET #show' do

    context 'User is logged in' do
      before 
        sign_in user
        get :show 
      end

      it "loads correct user details" do
        expect(assigns(:user)).to eq user
      end

    end

    context 'No user is logged in' do
      it 'redirects to login' do
        get :show, id: user.id
        expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

When i run rspec on the terminal i get this error:

```
/Users/joao1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load': /Users/joao1/Desktop/nameofapp/spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:29: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)
    from /Users/joao1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
    from /Users/joao1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/joao1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/joao1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1435:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/joao1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1433:in `each'
    from /Users/joao1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1433:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/joao1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:100:in `setup'
    from /Users/joao1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
    from /Users/joao1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
    from /Users/joao1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
    from /Users/joao1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/joao1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /Users/joao1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/joao1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/joao1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

How can i solve this and effectively test my user authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is a result of a typo in your program and it not matching up do end blocks. Looking more carefully I see you are missing a do statement from the before block. Change it to:

```
 before do
   sign_in user
   get :show 
 end
```

Comment: Thank you David that was it.

Comment: I got faillures on the code but at least the test ran. Thanks so much